# How to get collision to work with physical properties cloth

Tags: edit-mode

I would like to create an object which is covered with say a tarpaulin.
Being the first time I have ever attempted this I watched two different video tutorials and followed them EXACTLY but when I move my cloth (plane) down (on the Z axis) over a simple mesh cube the plane just slices through the cube instead of 'falling' over it as a piece of cloth would.
All scales have been set (to 1)
I add physical properties Collision to the cube.
I add lots of cuts (subdivide) to the plane.
I add physical properties CLOTH and select Cotton in the presets to the plane
I scroll down and select Collisions and set quality to 3, and select (ie tick) Self Collisions
This is exactly what the author of the video tutorial does.
However, when I move the plane down over the cube it simply 'cuts' through the cube.

There must be something else what the author does not cover but what is it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the file you linked, just adjusting the camera and hitting play, I get this:

[image]

I think that's what you want.  Collision is working.  So, why aren't you getting it?

One answer might be cached physics, which are one of those things that are supposed to help and yet always just get in the way.  Simplest way around this is to download your own file and run it; it'll work.  For future work, look on properties/physics/cloth/cache and "delete all bakes", then start and cancel a move operation on the object with cloth physics to reset the cache.

From comments: you want something fixed.  Play until it's how you want, then apply the modifier from the dropdown:

[image]

Comment: I am NOT using animation and didn't know that it is required to get it to work. The tutorial makes or shows no mention of animation.  If that is the case then how do I create a 'still' which I can add? I just want an object covered with (in my instance) a tarpaulin.

Comment: Yes, animation is required.  If you want a still mesh, play until it's where you want and "apply" the modifier from the dropdown menu to the right of the cloth modifier's name.

Comment: See edited answer for a picture of applying the modifier.

Comment: @JohnArnold Just out of curiosity, which tutorials are that where they show you how to put cloth on a cube without using animation? Or do they simply bake the simulation without watching it animated beforehand and then jump to the end frame to see the result?

Comment: They probably just skip playing it to save time.  You can bake instead of playing it if you want, but it's basically the same thing.  Been a really really long time since I looked at any physics tutorials myself though.

Comment: @Nathan I know how that works, I just wonder what kind of tutorial that is where they skip parts that are slightly important for beginners who are still learning it.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Oh sorry, thought it was John talking, misinterrpeted.

Comment: Sorry I can't remember the video tutorial and could not locate it when I searched in youtube. I did though find another tutorial which uses the animation but does not verbally refer to it. Too many tutorials assume the watcher knows certain things. Oh well I have learned how to make a 'tarpaulin' cover an object. I love to learn new stuff.